# Most compact way to connect pressure plate and piston

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a mob spawner trap with instant fall to lava lake.

[image: image description]

The actual thing I need to connect is (the block below piston isn't needed):

[image: image description]

I figured out double negation connection with 2 torches and 2 repeaters per piston, but it takes out a lot of space:

[image: image description]

Is there anything more compact? I thought people are making those huge enderman farms with pressure plates. That would be a lot of repeaters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have sticky pistons, this type of wiring is pretty compact:

[image: piston pusher]

Comment: I don't have them but still this answer shows the most compact solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just run the redstone up. Very resource friendly (no repeaters) and tileable. Though will cause a little bit more lag.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but nevertheless: You can do it a bit more compact. You just need one repeater and one redstone.

[image]